# Browser cannot load page after Laravel routing groups

Tags: php, laravel, http-redirect

I've just added Route groups to my route file in Laravel and now when I attempt to load my website, I get a message that says "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

I'm not sure why this is, can anyone see any errors in my routes file?

```
code redacted
```

One thing I tried that seemed to work but didn't make sense was `return`ing each of the `Route::get()` calls inside of these. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**edit:** When I edit the `root` route in the After Authentication Routes commented area to route to the `StaticController@getIndex` method, it works. Am I using the group filter incorrectly?

Comment: This happens only when you visit your home page only?

Comment: @RahilWazir Oh, no, sorry. I'll update the post, but it happens on any page. **edit**: I was wrong...updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this.

After taking a look at what the `auth` filter actually is...

```
Route::filter('auth', function() {
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

I realized that I was using it wrong.

If anyone else runs into this problem, the `auth` filter checks if a user is logged in, and if not, it redirects them to a login page (my problem was I was trying to access the login page while not logged in, causing an infinite loop.)